# Select 3 columns with specific keys from Wordpress postmeta table

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I want to make store locator using PHP and MySQL with Wordpress as CMS. I am using Pods plugin to create custom posts. There, I can add new locations. For each point I insert latitude and longitude. Now, as wordpress table works, these values are added as new rows in table, where meta_key is lat or lng and the meta_value is the value for that property.

Is there any way, probably using nested queries, to get the data in format:

| id | lat | lng |

from the data in format:

| id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value

I was trying to use query:

```
SELECT la.id AS id, la.lat AS lat, ln.lng AS lng
FROM (

    SELECT post_id AS id, meta_value AS lat
    FROM  `wp_postmeta` 
    WHERE  `meta_key` LIKE  'lat'
) AS la, (

    SELECT post_id AS id, meta_value AS lng
    FROM  `wp_postmeta` 
    WHERE  `meta_key` LIKE  'lng'
) AS ln
GROUP BY id
```

but it's returning only proper values for latitude and only one value for longitude repeated in each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't want to use subqueries in MySQL when you can avoid them.

Similarly, you don't need an aggregation.  Instead, you need a `join` condition:

```
select lat.post_id, lat.meta_value as lat, lng.meta_value as lng
from wp_postmeta lat join
     wp_postmeta lng
     on lat.post_id = lng.post_id and
        lat.meta_key = 'lat' and
        lng.meta_key = 'lng';
```

Comment: Wow, that is really great. Thank you for that answer, I've learned something new and useful!